# Exportar tabla con solo datos a csv o txt

Tags: vba, ms-access, visual, microsoft-office, basic

Estoy intentando hacer en access un código en una tabla el cual más tarde pretendo enviar el fichero por email de manera automática. La estructura de la tabla seria tal que así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado realizando lo siguiente:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo ObjectType:=acOutputTable, ObjectName:="MiTabla", OutputFormat:=acFormatTXT, Outputfile:=nombreFichero
```

El cual no ha sido muy exitoso ya que la estructura final que me exporta es algo tal que así.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando simplemente busco que solamente me exporte la información dentro de la tabla con la estructura de esta forma.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con un DoCmd.TransferText pero no me sirve ya que "No tengo permisos en la tabla"

Espero alguna respuesta.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba a:

Con la tabla de Access abierta, comprueba que los registros de la tabla no están bloqueados, entiendo que debes tener acceso a la misma para poder exportarla, no entiendo bien el error que comentas de "no tengo permisos" en la tabla, muestra el mensaje de error para ver qué sucede.

Desde Datos Externos-Archivo de Texto exportas los datos y creas una especificación para la exportación

Crea especificación:

-Selecciona ruta destino
-Aceptar

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/53MWE.png]

-Selecciona Ancho Fijo (como ya los tienes los datos delimitados por ; Ancho fijo es la mejor opción)
-Pulsa Avanzado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comprueba la configuración de la especificación de exportación, en el ejemplo he puesto 255 ancho, se puede adaptar, pero los datos que indicas...debería valer con ese ancho.
Ahí mismo en esa pantalla, "Guardar como" y dale un nombre a la especificación (en el ejemplo yo la he llamado Esp1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aceptar-Finalizar-Aceptar

Ya con esto, se habrán exportado los datos de la tabla (Yo la llamé Estructura, y al campo también "Estructura"

Una vez esté todo ok, en VBA puedes repetir la exportación:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportFixed, "Esp1", "Estructura", "D:\Temp\tmp.txt", 0
```

Comment: El error de los permisos del que hablaba es el siguiente:
Se ha producido el error '3027' en tiempo de ejecución:
"No se puede actualizar. Base de datos u objeto de solo lectura."

Comment: Revisando el error 3027, puede ser que el archivo que va a exportar no tiene una extensión de nombre de archivo válida que Microsoft Access espera. Revisa que la salida del archivo tiene extensión txt. Aunque en realidad está construido como CSV es un archivo de ancho fijo. ¿Has realizado la exportación como indiqué en el mensaje anterior, creando la exportación a mano guardando la especificación y ejecutando el DoCmd.TransferTex?

Comment: Gracias por tu paciencia. Era fallo mío al confundir tu VBA en el que ponías "Estructura" no especifiqué mi tabla (Fallo de novato). Hace exactamente lo que buscaba aunque no tengo muy claro como quitar los espacios que surgen entre campos en el txt... Una ultima pregunta de principiante. ¿Las exportaciones que yo haga en ese fichero access se guardaran en otros ordenadores o se tendrá que crear una nueva en otro PC?
Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Realmente lo que guarda es la especificación (Esp1) (Lo guarda como una tabla que incluso si fuera necesario se puede ver, pero está oculta) y queda vinculada a la Base de Datos, por lo que se ejecutará sin problemas en otro equipo, siempre claro que las rutas de salida existan y sean correctas. 
Yo no veo espacios en el ejemplo que pusiste...Solo es un campo Estructura. Mira a ver si en la tabla real que usas los tiene, porque en la exportación no los va a meter, ya que para Access es una cadena de texto